# P values and t statistics?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

I performed an experiment using two different methods on same object, the results of the experiments were

Method 1 70,72,70,75 and 77%

Method 2 80,81,67,75 and 82%

On basis on average I claimed that method 2 performs well. But I am asked to provide p values or t-statistics to confirm the results , how can I do that ?

Comment: You have not clearly described the situation. Are there 5 objects each of which was subject to both methods once (paired data), or a single object subject to ten experiments?

Comment: What do you mean by “performs well”? If 50% is good then both are good, if 90% is required, then none of them are. You can also compare both but, significant or not, you should also think about the practical meaning of the 4 point difference between 73% and 77%.

Comment: You should also consider the fact that even if the difference was big enough to be significant, with 5 observations you wouldn't have any real certainty about its magnitude.

Comment: The  data could be interpreted as result from the treatment based on two separate combination of medicines. The result e.g. 70 % may be understood as 70% of the patients got well. Siimilarly for method II. next item(s) '- patients  from other hospital for each of two methods . Thus, samples are unrelated or independent. Methods of treatment are separate. We can use assumption of independent samples for t-test. I shall write more about under my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of any other information about your setup, you presumably need to conduct an [independent samples t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_samples).

Here is some R code to demonstrate the use of the `t.test` function in R,

```
experiment1 <- c(70, 72, 70, 75, 77)
experiment2 <- c(80, 81, 67, 75, 82)
t.test(experiment1, experiment2)
```

and here is the output.

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  experiment1 and experiment2 
t = -1.3527, df = 5.895, p-value = 0.2257
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.830092   3.430092 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     72.8      77.0
```

Based on the fact that the p-value of the test is 0.3145, we are unable to reject the hypothesis that the data arise from populations with the same mean, that is, the difference in performance of the two methods is not statistically significant, and the observed differences are within the allowable limits of sampling uncertainty.

That said, your sample is probably way too small for the t-test to have any power to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: @conarch I'm not convinced that independent samples tests are right. You should clarify the situation as indicated in my other comment

Comment: @Glen_b The two cases in your comment to the question are not the only two scenarios. The plausible experimental setup that would make the independent samples t-test valid is that if there were a control and treatment group with 5 members each, or indeed with one member each where the treatment was administered 5 times.

Comment: @fgnu But neither of those are consistent with what the OP actually wrote: "two different methods on the same object".

Comment: Then the best interpretation is that the same object was treated to two distinct treatments on 5 distinct occasions, in which case the paired test would be appropriate. @conarch, you will need to clarify your question if you would like a more accurate answer. As it stands we are just speculating on semantics.

Comment: In fact, there were 5 subjects that participated in both experiments.

Comment: There is a typo in your code, the third value for method 2 should be 67, not 65.

Comment: p-value is being misinterpreted.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Feel free to post the correct interpretation in your answer to the question.

Comment: t- stattistic is always modular term. For an understanding of p-value read various posts including mine. And interestingly; you indicate two values of p in your post. you shoud respond and avoid evaluation of my postings.

Comment: That said, your sample is probably way too small for the t-test to have any power to reject the null hypothesis. The results are indicated in the question as percentage ( of a number of trials in each of five sets). Your presumption of small sample can not be construed. You may benefit if you read k- samples theory which acts as one of the approaches to a meta analysis.

Comment: Assuming p-value of .3145 is correct; it would mean that 1/3 of results for method-1 match the results (proportions) produced by method II. It indicates that in 70% (1-p) cases the results do not match with each other. Hence, the non sgnificant difference conclusion on the basis of t-statistic  is corroborated by alpha = 1 - p = .69. Actually p is indicating probabiliy of matching of results for two methods. alpha = 0.69 represents significant differences in two methods effectiveness.

Comment: Hence, the non sgnificant difference conclusion on the basis of t-statistic is corroborated by alpha = 1 - p = .69. This portion in aforesad comment may be treated as deleted

Comment: For sure t statistic has been computed incorrectly . It can not be minus.